# How do we exclude the cart and checkout from a customized theme?

Tags: checkout, cart

Is there a simple way to exclude the customized theme from the cart and checkout page (however still keeping the customized theme's header and footer). I simply want the original RWD design one from my magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

The Right Way™ to do this would be to actually forcefully change the design package and theme from within a layout observer to the default RWD theme whenever the cart or checkout layout handles exist. You would call your observer on the `layout_load_before` event:

```
<?php

class Demo_Module_Model_Observer
{

    public function layoutLoadBefore()
    {
        $checkoutHandles = ['checkout_cart_index', 'checkout_onepage_index'];
        $activeHandles = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();

        if(in_array($checkoutHandles, $activeHandles)){

            Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
                ->setPackageName('rwd')
                ->setTheme('default');
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `checkout` folder from the template folder in your custom theme and remove `checkout.xml` from your custom theme layout folder.

Comment: I would just remove what you don't want from the checkout.xml file.

Comment: They would still need to remove the checkout folder from the template folder, even if they chose to just remove some elements from checkout.xml, to allow fallback to load the default files.